# How to concatenate c(1,2,3) and c(4,5,6) to c(1,4,2,5,3,6) in R?

Tags: r, concatenation

How can I concatenate two vectors to get a vector with values alternatively from the first and second one?

**Input**

```
a<- c(1,2,3)
b<- c(4,5,6)
```

**Output**

```
c(1,4,2,5,3,6)
```

Comment: Try `c(rbind(a, b))`

Comment: That's not going to interleave.

Comment: @Elin did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way

```
> as.numeric(t(matrix(c(a,b), ncol = 2)))
[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```